# MVC 3 Request.Cookies value switches dynamically without purpose

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a problem with redirection in my BaseController (MVC 3) I have two langage versions of my site polish and english (set by `$.cookie` plugin). If, is set the english language and user wants to go to the polish URL - I want to make a proper redirection. But, anytime I make the redirection within the `OnActionExecuting` method, in the `ExecuteCore` method, I see that the language switches for some reason - see the `(*)` line.

What's more, in that scenario I get the infinite redirections between `OnActionExecuting` and `ExecuteCore` methods. Why ?

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    protected override void ExecuteCore()
    {
        if (Request.Cookies["language"] != null)
        {
            if (Request.Cookies["language"].Value != "pl-PL" && Request.Cookies["language"].Value != "en-US")
                Request.Cookies["language"].Value = "en-US";
        }
        else
            Request.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("language", "en-US"));

        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(Request.Cookies["language"].Value);
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;

        base.ExecuteCore();
    }

    protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        switch (filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName)
        {
            case "Onas":
                if (Request.Cookies["language"].Value == "en-US")
                {
                    filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("/About", true);
                    return;
                }
                break;
            case "About":
                if (Request.Cookies["language"].Value == "pl-PL")
                {
(*)                 filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("/Onas", true); // Request.Cookies["language"].Value will be en-US inside the ExecuteCore method - why ?
                    return;
                }
                break;
        }

        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the cookies Path property. You could get infinite redirections by having en-US on `/Onas` url and pl-PL on `/About` url.

Make sure to set global cookies with jQuery plugin with `{ path: '/' }`